# Asking MATLAB to beep (or send me an email) on any error

Tags: matlab

I have two MATLAB functions:

- `email_me_this(text)`
- `beep_now`

that I can call to email me a string and to emit a beep on the computer.

I would like to call these functions when something goes wrong with the execution of a script in MATLAB. I presume I can do this with a `try catch` block, but I was wondering if there was some other way to force this at a general level throughout a whole MATLAB session.

Comment: try-catch really is the best option. Any reason why you don't want to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to overload the [ERROR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/error.html) function. Thus, your code will be executed on *every* error thrown by Matlab.

```
function error(varargin)
%# email message. Note that varargin{2} contains error information, unless there is
%# only one input that is a structure.
email_me_this('there has been an error')
beep_now
%# call the builtin function error.m
builtin('error',varargin{:})
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting the following error when I call `beep_now` if I overload the `error` function `??? Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)
to change the limit.  Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer.`

Comment: In fact, I noticed that if I just have the following line in my overloaded function `error.m`: `disp('error');`, I see the word "error" printed on normal operations (e.g. opening a file with `Ctrl-D`).

Comment: @intrpc: If your call to `beep_now` produces an error, it'll call error, which calls `beep_now`, which produces an error, and so on. Thus, you should rename our `error` function, and make sure beep_now will work fine. Also, errors are thrown by many functions and then caught by try/catch statements. Your overloading function would be executed when this happens, as well, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas. I checked and `beep_now` works well itself if I don't overload the `error` function. `beep_now` is a small script that just runs this: `intensity = 0.15;
  player = audioplayer(intensity*sin(0:0.5:(0.35e3*2*pi)), 4*8192);
  play(player);`. It's also odd that the error function is executed even when I press `Ctrl-D` to open a file on the editor, isn't it? Maybe MATLAB relies on `try-catch` to find files?

Comment: @Jonas: I'm afraid this will only work when explicitly calling the ERROR function in your scripts/functions.. example, try to read a non-existent file: `fid=fopen('doesnt_exist','r'); data = fread(fid);` (standard error is still thrown even if you overload ERROR.m). @intrpc: NARGCHK is often used with ERROR function to check the correct number of input arguments in functions. It expects it not to throw an error if an empty string was returned by NARGCHK. This is just one of many examples, and I think this approach is very problematic and will give you many headaches... Just use try/catch

Comment: @Amro: I agree that it would be better to use try/catch, but I wanted to answer the OP's question. As to the error-calling functions, it seems that compiled functions wont call `error`.